# C# Try to fire an event to call function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, devexpress

When I press enter, which enables the buttonEditClient_PressEnter function, 
the buttonEditClient_ButtonClick function should be called.

```
private void buttonEditClient_PressEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //fire buttonEditClient_ButtonClick function
        }
    }

private async void buttonEditClient_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        //buttonEditClient_ButtonClick activated
    }
```

In the Designer:

```
this.buttonEditClient.ButtonClick += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventHandler(this.buttonEditClient_ButtonClick);
this.buttonEditClient.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.buttonEditClient_PressEnter);
```

If I try this:

```
private void buttonEditClient_PressEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        buttonEditClient_ButtonClick(sender, e)
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
 cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs' to 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs'
```

How can I activate the buttonEditClient_ButtonClick function?

Comment: try change `KeyEventArgs ` to `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs`

Comment: parameter `e` is `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs` => you have to convert `e` like `buttonEditClient_ButtonClick(sender, new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs())`

Answer (score 2):

A click event is inherently different from a keyboard event (e.g., one includes information about the pressed mouse button and cursor position, the other about the pressed key), so you can't pass your `KeyEventArgs` to the click handler, which expects a `ButtonPressedEventArgs`.

You have a few simple options here:

- Move your code from the button click handler to an extra function, and call that from both your handlers.
- Find a way to create a new `ButtonPressedEventArgs` instance inside the key handler, and then pass that instead of the `KeyEventArgs`. This would be a very slipshod solution, as you're literally making stuff up (what cursor position are you going to give it?).

The first solution could look something like this:

```
private void buttonEditClient_PressEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        buttonEditClientSubmit();
    }
}

private async void buttonEditClient_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
    buttonEditClientSubmit();
}

private void buttonEditClientSubmit()
{
    // your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you actually need anything from the `ButtonPressedEventArgs`. If you don't need anything from `ButtonPressedEventArgs`, you could just have both events call one function.

```csharp
private void Handle_buttonEditClient()
{
   // Do what you want to do when the button is pressed or has the "Enter" 
   // key pressed on it.
}

private void buttonEditClient_PressEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Handle_buttonEditClient();
    }
}

private void buttonEditClient_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Handle_buttonEditClient();
}
```

**Note**

I made `buttonEditClick_ButtonClick` synchronous, but if you leave it async the same thing applies. Just have both events call the same function.

If you need the `ButtonPressedEventArgs`, then it's like Anas Alweish says. You'll have to create an instance of `ButtonPressedEventArgs`. I'm not familiar with DevExpress, so I don't know how you'd do that. Maybe something like `new ButtonPressedEventArgs(buttonEditClient)`?;

[DevExpress Docs on ButtonPressedEventArgs](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs.-ctor.overloads)